# Blank page in OpenERP after module install

Tags: python, odoo

Maybe someone could help me.
I've installed Odoo (OpenERP) on localhost and I've installed many basic modules (15). I have a problem, after install `Expense Tracker` module the web client displays a blank page, in any section. I can't see also the `Settings` page, just the menu bar at the top.

If I install just the `Expense Tracker`, it works. So it isn't a module problem.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Could you find any error on terminal side??

Comment: No error on terminal. Just a blank page on the browser, the menu is displayed and I can change the page, but I can't see it.

Comment: if server logs are stuck on some .js??

Comment: Try using a Private browser session. Maybe you have some session/cache related issues.

Comment: I was using Odoo v9. Solved with v8. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience like yours. I think most of the time this happened because of a permission issue for certain files or database issue.

You cannot drop database on a production environment right?. So best way to solve it is removed last updated module source from addon folder and restart the odoo service.

Then update your addon source from working copy and install them.

Comment: And don't forget to set database backups in your server. Refer following articles.  https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-setup-a-regular-postgresql-database-backup-4728

Answer (score 0):

I is likely that you installed a corrupt module. Refer to the addons and delete a module that you installed last. This should sort out your problem as it did on my end